# Is there a way to activate overflow indicator for UITabBarController very long titles?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I have noticed a problem with some localizations and UITabBarController titles.

As far as I have noticed, the mechanism works like this:

- when the title is long UITabBarController decreases character spacing (kern) for the titles to try to match them to the size but it stops at some value
- there is no other mechanism to prevent the titles from the neighboring tabs do overlap and eventually it happens.

I do understand that the titles should be short and that that should be a main way to prevent this from happening, but if you have two-word titles that may be enough to cause the problem in some of the localizations.

Personally I would prefer to have some sort of the overflow indicator ('...') if this happens, but I am not sure how - it should be possible as UILabel can do this. At the moment I am trying to make some sort of the abbreviations in those problematic languages but it comes with problems - first I don't know those languages so I probably don't put abbreviation at the best place and second on many devices (like iPads) this is not needed so it may look bad on them.

Does someone know how to resolve this problem?